# Is there any SDK or Library that will allow me to read barcodes on the iPad2?

Tags: barcode, ipad-2

I have read the other questions on SO that I could find.  I want to read a barcode and have the return sent to my application, just like when I plug in a scanner to my computer.  I understand it is an image instead of a real scanner but couldn't find anything definitive on what I needed.

Is anything available?  It needs to read more than a UPC style barcode like the shopping barcode readers from the App Store.  It's not for shopping.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try the iPhone / C++ port in [zxing](http://code.google.com/p/zxing).